# How to get XML Element name in CSS

Tags: css, xml

I have a XML document and want to style it with CSS only.
How do I make sure that every element value is preceded with the element name followed by a `:`.

For example

```
<elem>Element</elem>
```

will be rendered as

`elem: Element`  when the css is applied.

I'm currently trying to do in the css file

```
elem:before { content: attr(name) ": ";}
```

but attr(name) doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to get the XML element name you are trying to style inside of the css file?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. The attr 'function' take as argument attribute name, not tag name. You should write some js to rewrite tag name into some data-* attribute and then attr css function could start working.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure it's possible.  Consider transforming XML with XSL instead.

Comment: Do you know an example of how that would work with XSL? That's really the only thing I need to worry about for the current task. Thanks in advance